# Rabbitmq - php amqp broken broken pipe error

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I am processing a huge xml document (which contains around a million entries) and subsequently importing a formatted version to the db using rabbitmq. Each time after publishing around 200,000 entries I receive a broken pipe error , and rabbitmq is unable to recover from it.

> Notice Error: fwrite(): send of 2651 bytes failed with errno=11
>   Resource temporarily unavailable in
>   [/var/www/ribbon/app/Console/Command/lib/php_amqplib/amqp.inc, line
>   439]
>
> Notice Error: fwrite(): send of 33 bytes failed with errno=104
>   Connection reset by peer in
>   [/var/www/ribbon/app/Console/Command/lib/php_amqplib/amqp.inc, line
>   439]
>
> Notice Error: fwrite(): send of 19 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken
>   pipe in [/var/www/ribbon/app/Console/Command/lib/php_amqplib/amqp.inc,
>   line 439]

This subsequently causes a node down error and the process needs to be manually killed to recover from it.

These are my class methods:-

```
public function publishMessage($message) {
    if (!isset($this->conn)) {
        $this->_createNewConnectionAndChannel();
    }
    try {
        $this->ch->basic_publish(
            new AMQPMessage($message, array('content_type' => 'text/plain')), 
            $this->defaults['exchange']['name'], 
            $this->defaults['binding']['routing_key']
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Caught exception : " . $e->getMessage();
        echo "Creating new connection.";
        $this->_createNewConnectionAndChannel();
        $this->publishMessage($message); // try again
    }
}

protected function _createNewConnectionAndChannel() {
    if (isset($this->conn)) {
        $this->conn->close();
    }

    if(isset($this->ch)) {
        $this->ch->close();
    }

    $this->conn = new AMQPConnection(
        $this->defaults['connection']['host'], 
        $this->defaults['connection']['port'], 
        $this->defaults['connection']['user'], 
        $this->defaults['connection']['pass']
    );
    $this->ch = $this->conn->channel();
    $this->ch->access_request($this->defaults['channel']['vhost'], false, false, true, true);
    $this->ch->basic_qos(0 , 20 , 0); // fair dispatching

    $this->ch->queue_declare(
        $this->defaults['queue']['name'],
        $this->defaults['queue']['passive'],
        $this->defaults['queue']['durable'],
        $this->defaults['queue']['exclusive'],
        $this->defaults['queue']['auto_delete']
    );

    $this->ch->exchange_declare(
        $this->defaults['exchange']['name'],
        $this->defaults['exchange']['type'],
        $this->defaults['exchange']['passive'],
        $this->defaults['exchange']['durable'],
        $this->defaults['exchange']['auto_delete']
    );

    $this->ch->queue_bind(
        $this->defaults['queue']['name'],
        $this->defaults['exchange']['name'],
        $this->defaults['binding']['routing_key']
    );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the [PECL AMQP extension](http://pecl.php.net/packages/amqp)? From experience, it is much less flaky and [better maintained](https://github.com/bkw/pecl-amqp-official).

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have added virtualhost access for your user on Rabbit MQ. I've created new user and forgot set access rights for "/" host which is used by default.

You can do that via management panel yourhost:15672 > Admin > click on user > Look for "Set permission".

P.S. I assume your RabbitMQ service is running, user exists and password is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this problem happens when you have a big content inside your message and your consumer expend too much time to process only one message, that is problem to response "ACK" to rabbit and try to consume another message.

When I have this problem for example I try to "fit" my messages, because its a products worker and each message had some like 1k products id, so I change to 100 products and it works very well.

You can read more about Detecting Dead TCP Connections with Heartbeats [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html)

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened to me when my connection to RabbitMQ was broken (the reason does not matter, in my case I intentionally stopped RabbitMQ service for some failure tests), and I was trying to reconnect to the RabbitMQ again by closing the old connection and initializing a new one, but I received `Broken pipe or closed connection` error.
The way I solved this problem was to use `reconnect()` method on my connection:

```
$channel->reconnect();
```

Comment: $channel->getConnection()->reconnect();

Comment: I have this error "broken pipe" exactly after $channel->getConnection()->reconnect(); Maybe you can tell me why?